# Populate a JList from a .txt reading line by line

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jlist, populate

I want to populate a JList from a .txt
I can't populate the JList...
Here's the code:

The .txt is formatted like this sample:

```
name1
name2
name3
```

The JList is declared in this way:

```
private javax.swing.JList jList1
```

This is the method used to read line by line:

```
 private void visualizzaRosa(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    fileSquadra = squadra.getText();
    try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Franky/Documents....");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        Jlist1.add(strline); //to populate jlist
        System.out.println(strLine); //to print on consolle
}
in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
{
        listModel.addElement(strline); 
        System.out.println(strLine); 
}

jList1.setModel(listModel);
```

Comment: oops! forgot to switch from `add()` to `addElement()`. Edited!

Comment: for JTextArea, inside the while loop you would need something like
`jTextArea1.append(strLine + "\n");`

Answer (score 1):

> and if i want to populate a Jtextarea instead of the jlist ????

Then use the read() method that is part of the API. THere is no need to write custom code:

```
textArea.read(...);
```